# Openvpn for client/server in same subnet

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, subnet

I'm trying to openvpn into an office network (192.168.1.0/24) from a client sitting on a network with the same subnet (also 192.168.1.0/24). It is a linux (ubuntu 9.10) server and windows client.

I followed this ubuntu [openvpn community documentation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN) and from what I can tell the base connection works fine. Of course I get a bunch of error/warnings about ip address collisions.

I was then trying to follow [this guide](http://nimlabs.org/~nim/dirtynat.html) on 'Dirty NAT tricks to get a VPN to work with clients also numbered in the private address space' but have not been successful. While I have a theoretical understanding of routing/masquerading I have relatively little practical experience and am unsure what is wrong.

Thus far, I have gotten to the point where the client connects to the server and is assigned an IP 10.22.8.10. However I am unable to ping the server ip 10.22.8.1 like the documentation suggests I should be able to.

The server config is basically identical to [guide 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN) with the modifications from [guide 2](http://nimlabs.org/~nim/dirtynat.html), i.e. setting the 'server-bridge 10.22.8.1 255.255.255.0 10.22.8.10 10.22.8.120' and 'push "route 10.22.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.22.8.1"'. In addition I add the tap interface configuration commands to up.sh.

The client config remains the same as [guide 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN).

Server 'ifconfig tap0' (edit: sorry if this looks screwy. In the preview pane of editing this post it looks fine)

> tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:ee:a8:04:8a:fc
>                 inet addr:10.22.8.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
>                 inet6 addr: fe80::ecee:a8ff:fe04:8afc/64 Scope:Link
>              UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>              RX packets:610 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>                TX packets:4533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>                 collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
>             RX bytes:111341 (111.3 KB)  TX bytes:650830 (650.8 KB)

The client log on connection:

> ```
>   Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 OpenVPN 2.1.1 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Dec 11 2009  
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See URL-REDACTED for more info.
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 LZO compression initialized
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '13a273ba'
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '360696c5'
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 UDPv4 link remote: REDACTED:1194
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:13 2010 TLS: Initial packet from REDACTED:1194, sid=11055cf2 cc0d1ea0
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 VERIFY OK: depth=1, REDACTED
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 VERIFY OK: depth=0, REDACTED
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:14 2010 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with REDACTED:1194
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.22.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.22.8.1,route-gateway 10.22.8.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.22.8.10 255.255.255.0'
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.254
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{7464875E-98E9-46AF-8F86-69FF32FFB722}.tap
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 TAP-Win32 Driver Version 9.6 
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 TAP-Win32 MTU=1500
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.22.8.10/255.255.255.0 on interface {7464875E-98E9-46AF-8F86-69FF32FFB722} [DHCP-serv: 10.22.8.0, lease-time: 31536000]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:17 2010 Successful ARP Flush on interface [33] {7464875E-98E9-46AF-8F86-69FF32FFB722}
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:22 2010 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:22 2010 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.22.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.22.8.1
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:22 2010 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=30 and dwForwardType=4
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:22 2010 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
>     Mon Mar 01 00:30:22 2010 Initialization Sequence Completed
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:14 2010 TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=648728/0 pkts=3922/0
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:14 2010 VERIFY OK: depth=1, REDACTED
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:14 2010 VERIFY OK: depth=0, REDACTED
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:15 2010 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:15 2010 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:15 2010 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:15 2010 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
>     Mon Mar 01 01:30:15 2010 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
> ```

The client route seems to be pushed ok (route print):

> ```
>   Active Routes:
>     Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
>           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.23     25
>         10.22.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.22.8.1       10.22.8.10     30
>         10.22.8.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
>        10.22.8.10  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
>       10.22.8.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
>     ...
> ```

However when I try to get to 10.22.8.1 it still seems to want to hop out of my local internet connection:

> ```
>   C:\Windows\system32>tracert 10.22.8.1
>     Tracing route to 10.22.8.1 over a maximum of 30 hops
>       1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  home.gateway [192.168.1.254]
>       2  nexthop.qld.iinet.net.au [203.55.228.88]  reports: Destination net unreachable.
> ```

Can anybody advise me as to what I'm doing wrong (or alternatively, if there is an easy, more tenable way of doing what I want - note that as per solution #1 in [guide 2](http://nimlabs.org/~nim/dirtynat.html), renaming either subnet is not possible)

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question, and I wouldn't mind trying to replicate it – though I think it might be a bit problematic for me to create this scenario. Based on your `route print`, you're using something other than XP – Windows Vista or 7, maybe? Can you let me know so I can create the appropriate VM for testing?

Comment: @fission: I'm using Windows 7. If you are interested, I can probably try it on a Windows XP machine. Let me know if you want any further information.

Answer (score 3):

Your default route metric value is lower than the 10.22.0.0/16 route and it gets routed to the default route. In resolving routes, if more than one route matches destination, the lower metric value route takes precedence.

Either push a default route through VPN or lower metric for 10.22.0.0/16 (increase metric for default route).

It should look like this:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.23    1000
    10.22.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.22.8.1       10.22.8.10     30
    10.22.8.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
   10.22.8.10  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
  10.22.8.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.22.8.10    286
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to remove the default route and add a route specific only to your VPN server and mark it available through your local router.

So, you should have 3 routes:

```
vpn.example.com   255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.254
192.168.1.0       255.255.255.0   gw 10.22.8.1
0.0.0.0           0.0.0.0         gw 10.22.8.1
```